Show full boot messages which are shortened
I have set up one of those waveshare 3,5" TFT displays and it works well.
But on (re)boot the boot messages are somehow shortened by a dot in the middle of each line so the beginning and end of each line fits on the display:

This kind of looks neat on first sight but I want to read the full line.
Also there is still some space on the right, I would like to use the whole tft width for the boot messages without them beeing cut off.
EDIT: after several reboots and carefully looking at the messages I managed to grab a picture in a second where the lines are still shown in full at the beginning and are mangled after some point it seems:

What causes this and how/where can this be configured? I searched the web for different phrases to find the cause for this but am unable to find anything regarding this topic.
Neither I could find described settings for that in the manuals/descriptions of the tft display driver.
my cmdline.txt looks like this:
console=serial0,115200 console=tty1 root=PARTUUID=b6d98939-02 rootfstype=ext4 fsck.repair=yes rootwait

Apart from the default raspbian config.txt the waveshare tft driver installation added following lines:
[all]
hdmi_force_hotplug=1
dtparam=i2c_arm=on
dtparam=spi=on
enable_uart=1
dtoverlay=tft35a:rotate=270
hdmi_group=2
hdmi_mode=1
hdmi_mode=87
hdmi_cvt 480 320 60 6 0 0 0
hdmi_drive=2


are the full messages in the logs?

yes, journalctl shows the full lines
